# How to build .exe of a solution

Tags: visual-studio-2012, projects-and-solutions

I recently finished a solution composed by 2 project. For this 2 project I have the `.exe` build, but I don't know how to do the exe of solution with VS 2012. Someone know how to do it?

Comment: you can't have a single exe for two projects. each project has its own .exe build

Answer (score 3):

When you compile & build a solution, the `.exe` that is created is placed into the folder relating to your current build configuration, usually either `Debug` or `Release`.

So navigate to the folder, on disk, using Windows Explorer, where the solution is stored, and look in the `Debug` folder. The compiled program is there.

If this is not what you are after, please post more details about these two projects and how they 'tie together'.

Comment: If these are two executable applications, then no, you are never going to have one. If one is a class library which is referenced into the main application, then you'll have a DLL and the EXE. So I would ask you to post a screenshot of a collapsed view of your Solution Explorer Window.

Comment: What I want is a exe file that contain the two project build, because I want to use my project without using the project folder.. It's difficult for me to explain because I'm not very good in english. Mmmm.... I want to have a exe that contain all elements of my solution.. The first project have a button that run the second project... I hope It's now clear in what I want.XD

Comment: If the second project is a class library, then yes, this is very possible. If it's another executable application, then no. 2 application projects (whether it's a console app or a WinForms app or a WPF app), 2 .exe's.

Comment: @DinoSauro Why do you have two projects anyway?

Comment: Because I develop a game that have a wpf menu and game_project develop with monogame. I put in wpf menù a button that when it's clicked it's run the game.

Comment: If you want to start another EXE (as in your Monogame app)  then you can use Process.Start (pathtoEXE) from your main EXE.